# Setting vector as a list component in R

Tags: list, r, allocation

I want to create a list which has 1 element called 'a' that holds a vector of doubles.

```
l<-list('a'=1:1000)
```

does the trick. 
However, what if I want to do it dynamically?

```
l<-list()
l['a']<-1:1000
```

does not work!
How can I allocate enough memory when creating the list?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Then you do

```
> l<-list()
> l[['a']]<-1:10
> l
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

which works fine. With lists, [...] gives you a list with the selected elements, where [[...]] gives you the selected element. See also the help page `?Extract`

EDIT : 
or, as Tim said, `l$a <- 1:10` does the same. The advantage of [[...]] lies in

```
> l <- list()
> aname <- 'a'
> l[[aname]] <- 1:10
> l
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: @tim : very correct. I added your solution. I normally use [[...]] with lists as I use vectors with name information, but that's off course totally dependent on the implementation.